# How to autocomplete path to include file with solid prefix?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, include

in Netbeans, when I start writing absolute path to file I get autocomplete for path. e.g. when write:

```php
require_once "D:/www/"
```

and I get autocomplete for path to file e.g.:

```
..
project1/
project2/
file1.php
file2.php
```

But when I use constant or variable prefix to path, e.g.:

```php
class Tools{
    // const
    const PATH_TO_PROJECT = 'D:/www/project1/';
    // or variable
    public $pathToProject = 'D:/www/project1/';
}
```

and write:

```php
require_once Tools::PATH_TO_PROJECT . '';
// or
$tools = new Tools();
require_once $tools->pathToProject . '';
```

I don't get autocomplete.
Is there any way how to achieve autocomplete for this style of includes? Or is there more elegant way to do this?

And what about Auto including Classes. Is there some good library for this: I prefer something more modular.


Thank's for help and excuse my basic English.

With the wishes of a beautiful day

Radek

Answer (score 0):

You can set include_path the code should be something like:

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').PATH_SEPARATOR.'D:/www/project1/');
```